# WISE Windows Installer Editor Launch Condition Problem - Version Checking

Tags: math, installation, windows-installer, wise

I am working on a WISE Installer that needs to run on Java Version 1.5 or greater. So I have it read the registry for the Java Runtime Environment and get the "CurrentVersion" variable - for example 1.6, and place it in a WISE property.

I am attempting to build a Launch Condition that prevents the Installer from continuing if it is run on a system with an older version of Java. For this I attempted to have it check my variable i.e.: (if) JAVAINSTALLED < 1.5 (then error out).  When I try to build this condition I get back an error message "real numbers not supported". It apparently works when you compare it to a whole number (as there are other launch conditions that do this)

So I am wondering what the best way to handle this is. I have thought of the idea of taking the variable and multiplying it by 10 so I can check for < 15 instead, but I do not know if this would work and not sure how to implement math functions with the limited control I have in WISE.

any ideas are greatly appreciated.  thanks!

(Note: Using Wise Installation Studio version 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a property as JAVAVERSION and the value "1.5" in your case. And Check the Launch condition against this property.. condition should look like

JAVAINSTALLED

Hope this should Work..

Yours,
Maddish-Packager

Comment: Sorry it's missed out.. condition is

JAVAINSTALLED<JAVAVERSION

Maddish-Packager

Answer (score 1):

How about treating the variable value as a string as in:

```
JAVAINSTALLED < "1.5"
```